# Finding the noise only part in a signal

Tags: audio-processing, noise-cancellation

I have signal which contains some noise only regions (glitch with the recording it seems).

The question is:

1. I would like to identify the discrete time samples where this noise part starts and ends. There are about 3 to 4 seconds of this noisy part available, there are 4 to 5 such instances, the total recording length is 153 seconds. The sampling frequency is 48 kHz.
2. I would also like to get to characterize the spectra of noise so that I can possibly try and remove it. How can I do this?

Comment: We'll need to know at least a bit about your noise!

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, I've answered a similar question here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/removing-background-noise-algorithm/66179#66179 so you can have a look.

Comment: @dsp user  that is close to what I am looking for, but how do I find the start of the noisy portion in discrete domain

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, can you open your file in a  sound editor and start from there (i.e. label the noisy parts manually)? If you're looking for a fully automatic algorithm, then you'll  need to know more about the noise.

Comment: @dsp user, what should I be knowing about the noise to automatically find the start of this noise phase

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, you'll have to know what your noise looks like (i.e.the  noise profile). If your noise overlaps with parts of the signal, then it's going to be difficult to extract the noise profile so you'll have to make some guesses perhaps based on your experience etc. When I mentioned a fully automatic process that was under the assumption the noise profile was known.